# How to understand I found that dress delivered still in the box to me?

Tags: word-meaning

> Before my father died, we had shopped for a party dress which made me feel like a dramatic Cinderella. But it was the wrong size. Later I totally forgot about the dress.
> My mother didn’t. ***The day before the dance, I found that dress, in the right size, _______ still in the box to me — gracefully, and lovingly.*** She just wanted her child to feel loved and showed that there still existed magic and beauty even in the face of hardships.

> A. composed
> B. thrown
> C. paid
> D. delivered

I failed to choose a word from the four to fill the gap. I've found that "[delivered](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/zht/%E8%A9%9E%E5%85%B8/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E/deliver)(given) to me" might work here, but " still in the box" and " gracefully and lovingly" don't seem to match it. Maybe I've mismatched them?  What's the author trying to show?

Comment: Presumably her mother brought her the dress still in its original box -- and "gracefully and lovingly" are describing her mother's gesture."She just wanted her child to feel loved..."

Comment: P.S. Does the original say "shopped a party dress" or "shopped for a party dress"?

Comment: Shopped a party dress.

Comment: _Delivered_ is the only possible option, but the whole sentence reads oddly to me. I would expect _[the dress] was delivered to me, still in its box_ or _she delivered it to me..._

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense. If it was delivered, that implies a professional service so of course it would still be in the box. And why would you "find" it rather than be given/receive/have it delivered to you (unless the delivery people dumped it in the back garden because you were out)? Is the intended meaning that it was delivered some time ago and waiting for the dance? No idea.

Comment: If this is an example of a question from a test, then it's badly worded. "shopped a party dress" is not idiomatic.  It should be either "went shopping for a dress", or just "bought a dress". In all honesty, I suspect the question may have been written by a non-native English speaker.  There are several issues, not just the one I mentioned.

Comment: "to shop *for* something" means to visit one or more places looking to buy the item, and  "to shop something" means to attempt to sell it.

Comment: @BillyKerr your first sentence is correct, but *It should be either ...* is complete nonsense.  "we had shopped a party dress" is just missing the word "for" after "shopped".

Comment: @RonJohn - yeah that works too.  There are probably many ways to say it.  I gave two valid options, I didn't mean there were only two. It was only a comment. I wasn't listing every possible option.

Answer (score 2):

*Delivered* is the only one that will work grammatically and semantically.
We need a verb that will accept "to me" as an indirect object. Obviously the dress was not paid to the daughter; *paid* can have an indirect object introduced by "to", but it would not work with the fragment indicating location "still in the box" between the verb and the object. *Thrown* can have an indirect object object introduced by "to", it would accept the fragment indicating location "still in the box" between the verb and the object but its meaning  implies a certain force/abruptness that would clash with the context of a loving mother.
As said in [@TimR's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/342763/how-to-understand-i-found-that-dress-delivered-still-in-the-box-to-me/342767#comment659428_342763) the mother had brought ("delivered") the dress in the original box, she hadn't opened the package coming from the shop.
"Gracefully, and lovingly" describe the mother's gesture, in spite of the sorrow of losing her husband, the mother had gone back to the shop to change the original dress for one the right size, thus showing her daughter that life must go on.

Comment: I thought much time had elapsed (enough for Cinderella to have forgotten about the dress) and in that time she had grown into it. The dress had been too baggy at the hips and bodice. Had it been too small and tight, it would probably have been returned to the store. Dad probably said "It will fit you soon enough. Keep it. Next time, take mom with you. She would have had you try it on at the store."

Comment: @TimR Most probably, but we can imagine lots of things!

Comment: Yes, as you had imagined the mother going back to the store to exchange the dress for one the right size :-)  My reading is based on **still in the box** and Cinderella's forgetfulness, which came upon her "later".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "delivered, "because it fits the context, referring to a dress delivered by a mother to her daughter. The context of the sentence describes how the daughter's mother found the correct size party dress and handed it to her daughter, showing the mother's love and care. The other options," composed," "thrown," and "paid," are not appropriate in this context because they do not describe the act of the mother delivering the dress to her daughter. So the correct answer is' delivered ', meaning the mother gave the dress to her daughter.